# TypeScript: `void` incompatible with optional/default parameter

Tags: typescript

It seems bizarre to me that while `undefined` and `null` are compatible with `void`, the reverse is not true, considerably eroding the utility of optional parameters:

```
function getThing(): string | void {}
function checkThing(val: string = 'abcd') {}
checkThing(getThing())

t.ts(3,12): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Specifying an optional arg without default value doesn't change the error, but specifying a union with `void` does (and generates that with default-initialize the parameter as expected).  It seems rather onerous to insist on declaring a `void` union on all optional parameters that may at any point in time be the target of the result of a void function.  What else would you do with a `void` parameter?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: `string | void` is not very useful as return type, `string | undefined` would work better IMO

Comment: You are saying that the function will either return a string, or not return anything at all.  You can't return both something and nothing.

Comment: Well it is possible to return either something or nothing.  I ended up just taking @artem's approach in returning `undefined` which is a value interpreted as an omitted parameter by TS (and either accepted as an optional arg or replaced with default value).

Comment: Nitzen - `void` type does not compose with optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample:

```
function getThing(): string | void {}
function checkThing(val: string = 'abcd') {}
checkThing(getThing())

t.ts(3,12): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Focus in on the error `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'`. `checkThing` expects a `string` and is given something that you said could be `void`. Hence the error.

> It seems rather onerous to insist on declaring a void union on all optional parameters that may at any point in time be the target of the result of a void function. What else would you do with a void parameter?

This is by design from the TypeScript team. You are entitled a different opinion and I can sympathise with your desires

Comment: Yes, I understand how type systems work in general.  The issue here is that the function parameter is optional and while `undefined` is interpreted as an omitted parameter (thus satisfying the signature), `void` is not.  The solution appears to be to use the `undefined` instead of `void` type.  I'm not sure what other purpose `void` could have as an argument, but maybe it exists precisely to prevent its propagation.  It also means I have to use `undefined` instead of `void` across the board, or consciously decide at every point which return values I want to be propagatable.